# call to javascript function doesnt work inside dojo require block (dojo ver 1.8)

Tags: javascript, dojo, call, amd

Calls to aanother javascript function arent executing. Code:

```
function btn_click(){
  require(["dojo/dom","dijit/registry"], function(dom,dijit){

    dom.byId("tbm_notes_results").innerHTML="New HTML";


    javascriptfn1;

    //code after 1

 });

  javascriptfn2;
  //code after 2
}
```

- Call to javascriptfn1 DOESNT execute, no error in console
- //code after 1 executes (commented out)
- Outside the REQUIRE, Call to javascriptfn2 DOESNT execute, no error in console
- //code after 2 executes (commented out)

Searching led me to the following

[Dojo AMD: Can't call a function inside a require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626821/dojo-amd-cant-call-a-function-inside-a-require)

I would appreciate if someone could explain it simpler for me (even a concept) and if possible tell me how to make it work (with/without my modules/package)

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call `javascriptfn1`, then you need to use parentheses.

```
javascriptfn1();
```

Same with `javascriptfn2`

Comment: doh! just when i thought i wasnt really a newbie! thank you so much! wonder why js doest give error!