# Calling a function from outside of require which is written inside of require in dojo

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, dojo

```
<html>
<head>    
<script>    
    require(["dojo/ready"],function(ready){

      function init(dataItem) {
          alert("inside init method")
          updateData(dataItem);
      }
      function updateData(dataItem){
       //inside this function, i am creating some breadcrumb and making each part of it a link.
       //Now that link is calling another method outerFunction()
      }
      ready(function(){
          init({
              type: "All Locations",
              id: "All_Locations"
          });
      });
   });

function outerFunction(jsonObj){
    init(jsonObj); // not working

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically i need to call `init()` from `outerFunction()`.
Please help me in this.

I need to call `init()` defined above , from `outerFunction()`. 
But this is not happening. 
Initially i tried to keep this `outerFunction()` inside require block. 
But then in that case, `outerFunction()` was not getting called from breadcrumb link.

So i had to move it outside. And now from outside, `outerFunction()` is getting called but `init()` is not getting called from `outerFunction()`

Or if in any way I can write ***outerFunction*** method inside ***require*** block and can make same call flow.

**Solution**: I have used dojo.subscribe() inside ready and dojo.publish() in outerFunction(). And it worked for me.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626821/dojo-amd-cant-call-a-function-inside-a-require?rq=1 It handles the same question you asked.

Comment: @MiBrock, thanks for the link you provided. It is indeed helpful. Although i solved it using publich/subscribe. I have detailed it in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's indeed a scope issue. You can solve it in various ways. One of them is to put `outerFunction()` inside the `require()` block like you mentioned.

However, if you call that function from somewhere else, you might encounter a problem. For a breadcrumb link (you mentioned) you could use an onclick handler inside the same `require()` block, for example:

```
on(breadcrumbLink, "click", function() {
    outerFunction({});
});
```

However, as soon as the amount of code increases, you'll have a problem if you put it all into the same `require()` block (because it will become unmaintainable), so you could split the `init()` function to a separate module, which can be included for both functions.

---

A third solution, though it is quite a bad practice if it's done quite often, is to put either one of them on the `window` scope. If you move the `init()` function to `window`, for example:

```
window.init = init;
```

Then you can access it from within the `outerFunction()`. Another way to do this is to move the `outerFunction()` inside the `require()` block and adding it to `window` as well, for example:

```
require(/** Stuff */, function() {
    function init() { }

    function outerFunction() { }
    window.outerFunction = outerFunction;
});
```

Comment: Is there any problem with using your last solution with `window.outerFunction = outerFunction;` if used in a single page application in which there would be a need of accessing anywhere between 50 and 100 functions that are inside the dojo require block?

Comment: @ScriptsConnect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice